# Web framework for an application that runs a hourly job and has simple GUI

Tags: django, spring, model-view-controller, daemon

I have to build a application that does 2 things -

1. Gathers data from a remote source and shoves it into a database. Runs every hour.
2. Provides a simple GUI to view that data.

Questions -

a. Will using a mvc framework like Spring or Django be overkill for this?

b. Do web frameworks support daemon jobs (assuming 1 is run as a daemon job)?

c. I have never used MQ or any messaging system before. Can something like that be used in this scenario?

At present, I plan to accomplish the above by writing a script for 1 and JS page for 2. But I would like to design an MVC application that can be expanded upon in the future, possibly adding more functionality/features.

Comment: MVC is primarily a UI framework with a routing engine, controllers and a model.  It doesn't have to support daemons or messaging queues; you write those separately, and then call/start them from your MVC application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B) spring provides with the `Schedule` annotation support for running jobs at specific times, for example atevery hour.

Comment: closest answer for the daemon question :). i ended up using nodejs for mvc and python for daemon jobs.